# how to get a handle on the status bar in iOS

Tags: ios, background, handle, statusbar

I have an audio recording application. And when it is recording in the background, I see a red horizontal bar on the top with my project name on it. I want to get a handle on that bar so that I can display additional things there. How do I get a handle on it and what exactly is that bar called?

Answer (score 1):

If your app is not running in the foreground you don't have access to the screen, so you can't get a handle to the status bar. And even if you could, you wouldn't be able to change it.

Comment: But the default app(Voice Memos) is able to continuously display the recorded time on the status bar when it is in the background. How does it do it?
Besides, that bar is displayed only when the application is running in the background.

Comment: Apple don't have to abide by the same rules that you and I have to.

Comment: What do you think about the SBStatusBarController? Can we use that to do the above?

Comment: Looks like a private framework, so you wouldn't be able to sell in the App Store though it would probably work.

Comment: I haven't been able to get it work. The methods here http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SBStatusBarController don't get recognised although the class declaration does. Also, I read that ios version 4.0 onwards UIStatusBar is used. But it only has methods to animate or hide.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a private framework? You mean it's not Apple's framework?

Comment: A private framework is one that exists but is not documented by Apple. APIs that are not documented cannot be used in apps for sale on the App Store.

Comment: Oh. Thank you for the explanation. Is there any other app(that is not Apple's) that you know of that is updating the status bar?